# Why does a Hermitian operator with singleton spectrum have to be scalar?

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

One proof of Schur's lemma proceeds by showing that a Hermitian intertwining operator of an irreducible representation (of a topological group on a Hilbert space) has a spectrum that contains only one element. Why does this suffice?

Answer (score 3):

If $A$ is a bounded normal operator on a Hilbert space with spectrum $\{ \lambda \}$, then $B=A-\lambda I$ is a normal operator with spectrum $\{0\}$. Because the norm and spectral radius are the same for a normal operator ...